# copying hashmaps

Tags: java

I have a structure

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, question>>> lang=new HashMap<String,HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, question>>>();

HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,question>> section= new HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,question>>();
HashMap<Integer,question> questions= new HashMap<Integer,question>();
```

based on my logic I fill questions, section

```
while(logic){
    for(someother logic){

        //make the skeleton structure of the object
        questions.add(integer,object);
    }
    section.add(integer,map3);
}
```

now I use this map2 as a skeleton and make changes

```
HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,object>> tempMap= new HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,object>>();
while(logicnew){
    while(logic 2){
        tempMap = new HashMap(section);
        while(logic 3){
            tempMap2 = new HashMap(tempMap.get(integer));
            //make my changes
        }
    }
    lang.add(integer,tempMap);
}
```

Multiple languages have multiple sections, multiple sections have multiple questions.
The problem is the values are getting over written i.e. if I have french text in the first language and english text in the second language, I just see english text in both the lang maps I make.  Could you please tell what is wrong?  Let me know if there is any better way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please format your code and use proper English formatting.

Comment: Its extremely difficult to figure out what you are doing here. If you want help, please provide as much details as possible. Abstraction doesn't get you anywhere.

Comment: Please post correct code so that we can help you. Besides, you should really create objects that means something instead of imbricating 3 levels of `HashMap`, you'll surely understands better the problem.

Comment: @LaiXinChu : All that I am trying to do is copy the hashmap map2 into map and reusing it map2 to make changes in object. what other details are required?

Comment: @all : I made some changes and explained with an example.  Hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deep cloned (using object `serialization` and `deserialization`) the section `hashmap` and stored in the temp `hashmap` and used the temp `hashmap` to add the question text which can now be added according to the language, making my lang `hashmap`.

Answer (score 2):

The HashMap is an object that is passed by reference (You should read up on this).

If you want to reuse map2, make sure you clone map2 properly. Otherwise, modifications that you make to map2 will reflect across all the HashMap instances.

Do this before reusing map2:

```
map2 = (HashMap) map2.clone();
```

Do note that this is a shallow copy.

Read here to find out more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#clone%28%29

Deep clone of HashMap:

```
public HashMap deepClone(HashMap map) {
    HashMap clone = new HashMap();
    Iterator it = map.keySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Object key = it.next();
        Object value = map.get(key);
        clone.put(key.clone(), value.clone());
    }
    return clone;
}
```

This is just a sample implementation giving you a template to work with. You should ensure that the HashMap is typesafe, and that the key and the value have a deep clone implementation of Object.clone()

Comment: This will not help. HashMap.clone does not clone keys and values.

Comment: Updated answer to include deep clone

Answer (score 0):

When you create temp hash map from map2 it create new object of map. But values of this new map (tempMap) is same objects you have in you map2. So if you change value object in tempMap - same changes will be in map2. Simple cloning does not help - it clones only HashMap, not it's keys and objects. So you have to clone your objects (ke) when copy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are copying `HashMap`s using shallow copy, which is the default behaviour of all Java collections.
Let's simplify this to only one level of `HashMap`. Consider the following code:

```
Date date1 = new Date(1000);
Date date2 = new Date(2000);
HashMap<String, Date> map1 = new HashMap<String, Date>();
map1.put("one", date1);
map1.put("two", date2);
HashMap<String, Date> map2 = new HashMap<String, Date>(map1);
map2.get("one").setTime(3000);
```

What happens is that the second `HashMap` (`map2`) will contain the same instances of `Date`s that `map1` contains. `date1`, `map1.get("one")` and `map2.get("one")` will refer to the same `Date` object, so the following expressions will all return `3000` as the result:

```
date1.getTime();
map1.get("one").getTime();
map2.get("one").getTime();
```

This happens when you put another `HashMap` into a `HashMap`. From the second iteration you will modify the same `HashMap` over and over.